# install python modules in a web server hosted by hostgator

Tags: php, python

i'm working on a project using python and php, now when i run python on my mac terminal it runs perfect but when i try execute a command from my php on my localhost or live server it keep giving me this error below...can some one with me some tips on how to install python modules on a server using ssh or any other way.. thank you in advance!

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "demo.py", line 7, in <module>
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

 here is my php code...
 $data = "hello world";
 $cmd = "/usr/bin/python demo.py '$data' 2>&1";
 $response = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: You probably have more than one Python. Use full path to your Python installation

Comment: how do you execute your python script via php ? put your php code

Comment: ok added my php code ... and i am using the python version that comes with my mac pro  version 2.7....

Comment: Maybe too late to reply. But, @isramos329, have you tried setting up the `virtualenv` there?
If you haven't, you can follow this link: http://altbin.net/installing-python-modules-on-hostgator-shared-hosting-using-virtualenv

Comment: @sam thank you for the feedback and the link

Answer (score 7):

According to the official support article from Hostgator, **requests** module is not currently installed on all Linux servers. That is why `import requests` doesn't work. Installing modules by users is not allowed on Hostgator shared servers, so we could not use modules not installed.

Reference:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/python-modules